# TS/JS arrow function changing value of `this`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, arrow-functions

Using TypeScript v1.7.5, the context of `this` appears to be getting confused, or perhaps not transpiled correctly. Or I'm missing something. Inside of an arrow function, `this` is changing, when I expected it to still refer to the same `this` as outside the function. I've debugged the situation and the outcome is indicated in comments below.

**Source TS**

```
// Debug: "this" is an instance of the class -- good.
FS.exists(dbPath, (exists: boolean) => {
    // Debug: "this" is an instance of the global object -- not good.
    ...
});
```

**Resulting JS (ES5)**

```
FS.exists(dbPath, function (exists) {
    ...
});
```

I was expecting the resulting JS to bind the callback as follows:

```
FS.exists(dbPath, function (exists) {
    ...
}.bind(this));
```

I need to preserve the value of `this` inside the callback, hence I'm using arrow functions throughout my code. But I'm confused as to why this doesn't appear to be working correctly.

**Note**

If, and only if, I specifically attempt to use `this` within the arrow function, then TypeScript creates this workaround:

```
var _this = this;

FS.exists(dbPath, function (exists) {
    var _x = this;
});
```

Okay, fine, but wouldn't it have been better to use bind? This still doesn't fix the problem of me calling functions from within the arrow function. Those function calls will lose the context of `this`, which is not the appropriate behavior.

Comment: Have you identified situations where the transpiled code does not behave correctly? The transpiler will not create the `_this` variable unless it needs to. I don't understand your comment about *This still doesn't fix the problem of me calling functions from within the arrow function. Those function calls will lose the context of this,* Can you give an example of such a function call?

Comment: As it turns out, it was my fault and I was confused regarding what TS was doing in regards to arrow functions during transpilation. In the end, I was storing references to instance functions and then calling them later, from within an arrow function. Those stored instances were then assuming the `this` context of the nested arrow function. So I just updated the function references to bind to the correct version of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the desired behavior by the Typescript compiler.

ES6 fat arrow functions `=>` **don't actually bind `this`**. Instead, `this` actually falls through to the upper scope. Same with `arguments`, which you can't use inside a fat arrow function, because they will fall through to the upper scope.

So, binding all the time would be incorrect behavior according to the spec. And it would be an undesired behavior to always reference `this` from the parent scope inside a function if you aren't using it. This looks like correct optimization on the part of the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Interesting. I've narrowed down my issue some more and understand now what's going on. But this was confusing to me; can you provide a link to your source?

Comment: @JoshM. source of what?

Comment: References to spec, or details on why arrow functions are transpiled in this way?

Comment: Also, I understand that the ES6 arrow functions aren't binding `this`, but it would be the same affect as a non-arrow-function binding `this` -- it would reference the `this` at the time of the binding; the same `this` which the arrow function would reference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions `lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target)`

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for TypeScript spec/reasoning. I understand ES6 arrow functions in regard to binding, or lack thereof.